# GLSL 330 Point-Light and Shadow map wierdness

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a fragment shader that calculates directional, point and spot lights. Without shadow map, this works fine. What's strange is that after adding the shadow map (sampler2D), point light some how stomps the shadow. Here's my fragment shader: (skip to bottom to see comments for details)

```
#version 330 core

const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 4;
const int MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS = 4;

in vec2 TexCoord0;
in vec3 WorldNormal0;
in vec3 WorldPos0;
in vec4 LightSpacePos0;
in vec3 Tangent0;

out vec4 FragmentColor;

struct BaseLight
{
    vec3 Color;
    float AmbientIntensity;
    float DiffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
    BaseLight Base;
    vec3 Direction;
};

struct Attenuation
{
    float Constant;
    float Linear;
    float Exp;
};

struct PointLight
{
    BaseLight Base;
    vec3 Position;
    Attenuation Atten;
};

struct SpotLight
{
    PointLight Base;
    vec3 Direction;
    float Cutoff;
};

uniform int gNumPointLights;
uniform int gNumSpotLights;
uniform DirectionalLight gDirectionalLight;
uniform PointLight gPointLights[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight gSpotLights[MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS];
uniform sampler2D gTextureSampler0; //unit 0
uniform sampler2D gShadowMap;       //unit 1
uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;
uniform float gMatSpecularIntensity;
uniform float gSpecularPower;

float CalculateShadowFactor(vec4 light_space_pos)
{
    //perspective divide
    vec3 projected_coords = light_space_pos.xyz / light_space_pos.w;
    //map [-1, 1] to [0, 1]
    vec2 uv_coords;
    uv_coords.x = 0.5 * projected_coords.x + 0.5;
    uv_coords.y = 0.5 * projected_coords.y + 0.5;
    float z = 0.5 * projected_coords.z + 0.5;
    float depth = texture(gShadowMap, uv_coords).x;
    if (depth < z - 0.0005)
    {
        return 0.5; //in shadow
    }
    else
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
}

vec4 CalculateLightInternal(BaseLight light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal)
{
    vec4 ambient_color = vec4(light.Color * light.AmbientIntensity, 1.0f);
    float diffuse_factor = dot(normal, -direction);

    vec4 diffuse_color  = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec4 specular_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (diffuse_factor > 0)
    {
        diffuse_color = vec4(light.Color * light.DiffuseIntensity * diffuse_factor, 1.0f);
        vec3 vertex_to_eye = normalize(gEyeWorldPos - WorldPos0);
        vec3 light_reflect = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));
        float specular_factor = dot(vertex_to_eye, light_reflect);
        if (specular_factor > 0)
        {
            specular_factor = pow(specular_factor, gSpecularPower);
            specular_color = vec4(light.Color * gMatSpecularIntensity * specular_factor, 1.0f);
        }
    }

    return ambient_color + diffuse_color + specular_color;
}

vec4 CalculateDirectionalLight(vec3 normal)
{
    return CalculateLightInternal(gDirectionalLight.Base, gDirectionalLight.Direction, normal);
}

vec4 CalculatePointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_direction = WorldPos0 - light.Position;
    float dist = length(light_direction);
    light_direction = normalize(light_direction);

    vec4 color = CalculateLightInternal(light.Base, light_direction, normal);
    float inv_attenuation =  1.0 / (light.Atten.Constant + light.Atten.Linear * dist + light.Atten.Exp * dist * dist);

    return color * inv_attenuation;
}

vec4 CalculateSpotLight(SpotLight light, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_to_pixel = normalize(WorldPos0 - light.Base.Position);
    float spot_factor = dot(light_to_pixel, light.Direction);

    if (spot_factor > light.Cutoff)
    {
        vec4 color = CalculatePointLight(light.Base, normal);
        return color * (1.0 - (1.0 - spot_factor) * 1.0/(1.0 - light.Cutoff));   //remaps to [0,1] from cosine value so that it's a smooth fall-off
    }
    else
    {
        return vec4(0,0,0,0);
    }
}

void main()
{
    float shadow_factor = CalculateShadowFactor(LightSpacePos0);
    vec4 texture_color = texture( gTextureSampler0, TexCoord0 );
    vec3 pixel_normal = normalize(WorldNormal0);
    vec4 total_light = CalculateDirectionalLight(pixel_normal);

    for (int i = 0; i < gNumSpotLights; ++i)
    {
        total_light += CalculateSpotLight(gSpotLights[i], pixel_normal);
    }

    //If uncomment the for-loop below, the shadow disappears ...
    //I have tried even setting gNumPointLights to 0 and some how
    //it still "kills" the shadow ...
    //I also tried changing the logic to total_light += vec4(0);
    //magically this still kills it.
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < gNumPointLights; ++i)
    {
        total_light += CalculatePointLight(gPointLights[i], pixel_normal);
    }
     */

    FragmentColor = texture_color * total_light * shadow_factor;
}
```

commented out the for-loop and shadows are fine!
[image: correct rendering with shadows]

uncommented the for-loop and the shadows are gone without any other modifications. I tried this even with the logic inside the loop removed and the shadows still won't show up.
[image: shadows gone with the for-loop uncommented]

Here are some extra information: I'm running it on Mac OS 10.11.6 with XCode. I do check my shaders after compile and after linking. No errors are shown.

So why is this happening? I tried everything and I'm out of ideas, please help!

Comment: Are all of your uniforms correctly queried by location at runtime? Uncommenting the second loop will change the state of `gNumPointLights` and `gPointLights [...]` from inactive to active and is likely to jumble the locations assigned to other uniforms. My intuition tells me you made a bad assumption about the uniform array locations (in particular, the way that arrays of `struct` work). Are you querying the location of the individual fields of the struct?

Comment: I believe so, they are queried one by one via the string: "gPointLights[%d].Base.Color" where %d would be replaced with 0, 1, 2 and 3. What's strange is that the for-loop for spot light is totally fine (removing it or leaving it in does not change the shader's behavior).

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, it turns out to be unused uniform variables messing things up.